# Discord.py sending multiple images in one line

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I started to make bots with "discord.py" 2 days ago, and I made one bot which is great.

The bot is made about a game in which you create teams of 3 with the characters you have.

One of the functions of my bot is to recommend random teams and show the image of each character of the team.The only problem is that I want to make the characters images show in **one line and not 3 new lines.**

Here is how it looks right now: https://prnt.sc/s7wg9b

Comment: I only imagined this question would come from an arena clicker lol, I have been working with something similiar and this is an useful question.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for something impossible.
It is not possible to have a custom arrangement of images on the Discord client. There are some fixed places where you can have an image.
Displaying separate images in one line isn't a possible configuration.

What you can do is to use an imaging library such as [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to create a new image with those images next to each other.